# Why can't I open Remix IDE in my browser?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

[image: Remix IDE error screen]

I can open Remix in the past smoothly, but today I can't open it anymore.
The web page reminds me to do a hard refresh. I tried for many times, but it doesn't work.
I have also tried to use another browser, change my proxy server and restart my computer. None of these solved my problem.
I can't reinstall my browser because my crypto wallet was plugged to it.

I wonder why this error occurs and how I can solve this to use Remix in my browser normally.

Comment: Which error does it log in the console? (Similar to `Error loading Remix: ...?` and potentially more). But you probably have more luck rasing an issue directly in their [github repo](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/)

Comment: Today I get up and retry to enter Remix. It's accessible now. But I didn't save the log...